# When to put data in hard code vs in a database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and have a concept question. Say I'm developing a website for an airline. Where do I put the list of destinations? I need it all the time and it does not change often so putting it in hard code would be the fastest (right?). On the other hand, data belongs in the database (right?).

Would putting it in a database and loading it all into a list when the server is started make sense? If yes, any quick pointer towards the right data structure would be appreciated (e.g., static class?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you don't hard code anything you don't want to redeploy your application to change, keeping in mind you might be mid-way through a change to the project when a sudden need to redeploy happens.

To be specific, don't hard code this. You put it in the database and make use of caching to keep the data responsive. There are lots of ways to achieve caching and the best for you depends on how you're going to be surfacing the data. If it's an AJAX-y dropdown, you'll want a JSON endpoint with cache headers so the browser can keep its own cache and regardless you'll probably use the ASP.NET cache for your own code.

Edit: To talk about the static class - this is probably fine but keep in mind this means the data will always take up space regardless of memory issues the server might be having. Using a cache layer lets the server hold or dump depending on how often the data is used and what sort of memory constraints it's current under. In your case, this particular data seems integral to your application so using a static class might be beneficial. Just be sure you're not POPULATING that class from multiple threads or you could get some strange behavior.

Edit edit: It will take up memory as long as your application is alive. If the server has a lot of problems, it might just take your whole application down to keep itself running. A cache would at least dump first rather than going down.

Comment: Very helpful insights to the point I'm at, many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well you should not hard-code this list, that's for sure; any time a destination needs to be added or removed, you'd need to recode and redeploy the application (and these things change more often than you might think!)

So definitely a database of some kind (consider also that you'll probably need to provide some kind of Admin interface to let the Airline add/remove/disable destinations, etc).

In terms of the data structure, and whether or not to hold it all in memory, you probably need to think a little bit about the shape of the data first. Because it's probably not just a simple list of destinations - it's more likely a graph of departure points and destinations - one departure point will probably have *many* destinations, and destinations themselves may well be departure points.

i.e. Departures/Destinations have a many to many relationship with each other.

With that in mind, you can see that the size of the data could actually be much much larger than you think. So rather than trying to cache this all in memory, the best approach would be something like

- Customer visits the site and the page hits a JSON endpoint (e.g a Web Service) via Ajax to populate the list of Departure points from them to choose from in the "Where do you want to go from" dropdown
- Customer chooses a Departure point and a *second* ajax call retrieves the list of currently available destinations for that departure point only and loads it into the "Where do you want to go to?" box.

You can always use a cache once users start loading up destination points, but I personally would not load it all up front - it would also mean you'd need a way to refresh the cache whenever the list changes, without bringing down the application.

Comment: Also many thanks to you. So my understanding now: I should organize all data access as common db queries (select from where) (i.e., both Ajax calls in your example), plus as a second step see if caching common db query results makes sense. Right?

Comment: @FrankSeifert yes exactly. I would build it without a cache first, and then later on you can implement a cache if you find that the database is getting hit too much (a good thing for the airline!)

Comment: Both answers to the question are excellent, FIY: I threw a coin to decide which answer to accept and Erik won.

Comment: Best 2 out of 3? only joking :)

Comment: I saw the accept and came to be reminded of the question. I hadn't seen your answer (since I was first!) but I'm giving you an upvote to even out the difference as it is a very good answer. :)

Comment: @ErikNoren thanks - yours too (I already +1'd it :)